# Get List of Windows services with file version of the executable

Tags: service, wmi, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use PowerShell 3.0 to return a list of services with properties like Name, DisplayName, Path, and Version of the executable. I am using the following code:

```bsh
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
  ? {$_.Name -like '*sharepoint*'} |
  Select Name, DisplayName, State,
    @{Name="Path";Expression={$_.PathName.Split('"')[1]}},
    @{Name="Version";Expression={((($_.PathName.Split('"')[1]) | Get-Item).VersionInfo.FileVersion)}} |
  Format-List
```

I get everything back, except for the file version. I know I can break up the command, use a custom object, etc. but I would like to know what I am doing wrong here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At a quick glance, Get-Item might be operating on the wrong value. Shouldn't `$_` be the file itself at that point in the pipeline? If it is, I think `(gci $_).VersionInfo.FileVersion` might be close to what you're looking for.

Comment: AFAICS the code should work provided that the path in the service commandline actually is in double quotes. What output do you get when you replace the `Select ... | Format-List` with just `Select -Expand PathName`?